# When do queries with very large "WHERE x IN" clauses perform badly?

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have always been under the impression that queries with large `WHERE x IN` clauses perform  badly.

For example, let's say I have the following table

```
psql> \d examples


| Column  | Type                  | Modifiers
| id      | integer               | not null default nextval('id_seq'::regclass)
| flag    | boolean               | not null
| date    | timestamp             | not null
| comment | character varying(16) | not null
Indexes:
   "example_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

If I query this table using a `WHERE id IN` clause with 100k ids it actually returns fairly quickly (there are 100ks rows in the table):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT * FROM examples WHERE id IN (1, 2, ...., 100000);

Index Scan using examples_pkey on examples  (cost=0.15..15012.60 rows=610 width=104) (actual time=18.380..18.380 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{1, 2, ... 100000}'::integer[]))
 Planning time: 45.832 ms
 Execution time: 42.708 ms
```

The planner has rewritten the query to use `id = ANY` with my list of IDs so I assume this is just equivalent or the planner knows that's faster.

I have had other queries before where replacing large `WHERE IN` clauses with a subquery has greatly improved the speed of the query. My query here is very simple, so the question is:

Is it true that queries with large `WHERE IN` clauses actually perform badly? If so in which cases is that the case (assuming columns are indexes etc).

Answer (score 0):

The parser transforms `IN` expressions with more than one element in the list into `=ANY` expressions.

If there is a B-tree index on the column, it can always be used.

The only performance problem I can imagine is that the optimizer may estimate the number of result rows wrongly and choose a sequential scan when an index scan would actually be faster.

Experiments show that the optimizer estimates one result row per list entry for unique columns, with a maximum of the number of rows in the table. This is a reasonable estimate, but if there are many elements in the list that do not match or there are duplicates, the estimate can easily be too high.